# Is it possible to filter through results and assign to variable?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

Currently I am creating a hash table with ClientCode as the key and values being any groups within the AD that have the 'Clientcode_' in its name. For example groups called 'Managers_for_client_1234_group' and 'Developers_for_client_1234_group'

```
$clientTable = @{ }

foreach ($row in $cemTable) {
    $clientCode = "$($row.ClientCode)"
    $groups = @(Get-ADGroup -Filter "Name -like '*$($row.ClientCode)_*'" -SearchScope OneLevel -SearchBase "OU=Client-related Groups,OU=SomeGroups,DC=somecompany,DC=com" | select -Expand Name)
    write-host "Found $($groups.count) group(s) for: $($row.ClientCode)"
    $clientTable[$clientCode] = $groups -join ","
}
```

$clientTable

I now want to search through the results of my Get-AdGroup search and assign them to a variables depending on the group. For example all the groups within my search that are managers will be assigned to managers variable and the same for other roles. This will allow me to automate and change telemetry in the future if i want to change/restrict/give access etc. So far i've edited it to this.

```
foreach($row in $cemTable) {

    $clientCode = "$($row.ClientCode)"

    $groups = @(Get-ADGroup -Filter "Name -like '*$($row.ClientCode)_*'" -SearchScope OneLevel -SearchBase "OU=Client-related Groups,OU=Some Groups,DC=somecompany,DC=com" | select -Expand Name)

    write-host "Found $($groups.count) group(s) for: $($row.ClientCode)"

    $managers_group =

    $developers_group =

}
```

#### UPDATE

```
$combined = @()
foreach($rec in $hashTable) { 

    if (!($Combined | ? { $_.ClientCode -eq $rec.ClientCode })) {

        $filter = "*$($rec.ClientCode)_*"
        $groups = (Get-ADGroup -Filter 'Name -like $filter' -SearchScope OneLevel -SearchBase $MY_OU | select Name).Name
        $managers = $groups | ? { $_ -like "_Man*" }
        $developers = $groups | ? {$_ -like "_Dev*" }

        $object = [PSCustomObject]@{
            ClientCode = $rec.ClientCode
            Groups = $groups
            Managers = $managers
            Developers = $developers
        }

        $Combined += $object
    }
}

$combined
$managers.Count
$developers.Count
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the $groups you already have to create new variable with filtered objects.

```
$groups = (Get-ADGroup -Filter "Name -like '*$($row.ClientCode)_*'" -SearchScope OneLevel -SearchBase "OU=Client-related Groups,OU=Some Groups,DC=somecompany,DC=com" | select -Expand Name).Name
$managers = $groups | ? { $_ -like "Manager*" }
$developers = $groups | ? {$_ -like "Developers*" }
```

Once you have the three things, you can save them to a list of PSObject.

**Create a list of objects**

```
$combined = @()
foreach($rec in $csv) { 

    if (!($Combined | ? { $_.ClientCode -eq $rec.ClientCode })) {

        $filter = "*$($rec.ClientCode)_*"
        $groups = (Get-ADGroup -Filter 'Name -like $filter' -SearchScope OneLevel -SearchBase "OU=Client-related Groups,OU=Some Groups,DC=somecompany,DC=com" | select Name).Name
        $managers = $groups | ? { $_ -like "Manager*" }
        $developers = $groups | ? {$_ -like "Developers*" }

        $object = [PSCustomObject]@{
            ClientCode = $rec.ClientCode
            Groups = $groups
            Managers = $managers
            Developers = $developers
        }

        $Combined += $object
    }
}

$combined
```

**Update**

Note that managers and developers are part of `$combined` list. Each item in $combined will have a different count of managers and developers, which is I believe what you are looking for.

```
# Use this after you are done with your foreach loop to display the values in $combined
$combined | % { Write-Output "$($_.ClientCode) has $($_.Groups.Count) groups, $($_.Managers.Count) managers, and $($_.Developers.Count) developers" }
```

You can also look up groups, managers or developers for specific clientCode like this,

```
$result = $combined | ? {$_.ClientCode -eq "TestClientCode"}
$result.Groups
$result.Managers
$result.Developers
```

Comment: i still have 0 assigned to my variable when i do $managers.count

Comment: I removed the @() around groups.. and added .Name at the end. Should fix it

Comment: hmmm, doesn't seem to work im not sure what's wrong

Comment: @ineedhelp check the name of groups in $groups to see if any starts with Manager or Developer

Comment: they do exist, im wondering if it has anything to do with my $cemTable being hashtable. Is it possible to do a foreach on a hash table? I think in your answer you are doing it on the csv.

Comment: @ineedhelp if you are using the query like above, i dont see why it wont work. can you paste the one you are running  thats giving you blank managers and developers? $cemtable doesnt have anythign to do with the managers and developers as its based on the groups. So, structure of the groups matter.. groups should only be a list of strings (group names)

Comment: @ineedhelp use breakpoint to see the values in $groups ... and see what values it has. Values should all be simple strings in multiple lines

Comment: where should i paste the script i am running?

Comment: @ineedhelp In your post, you said, *Managers_for_client_1234_group' and 'Developers_for_client_1234_group'*... but in your code, you are searching for _Managers.. that would yield 0 results. Change your statement for managers to be like, `$managers = $groups | ? { $_ -like "Man*" }` Without underscore before Man.

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
$managers = $groups -like "Manager*" 
$developers = $groups -like "Developers*"
```

Then use

```
$managers.count
$developers.count
```

to see how many items are stored in your variable